# HTML CSS show image on polygon mouse over

Tags: html, css, svg, polygon, mouseover

I am pretty new to web development and need to create an interactive map where various info pops up on mouse over certain areas.

Is it possible to have an image appear or change visibility on mouse over a SVG polygon?

I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: For people to answer your question you need to show your code, tells us what exactly is the issue you are facing in your code and anything you tried to tackle the issue in your code. See I used the word `code` means you need to post your code. ready this before posting https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes.  Have a look here to start with https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/